# What is Space 'made' of?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, universe, vacuum

I have submitted my question, as I have been unable to request further information from the responders to it, as the system advised that there were 705 too many characters.  Apologies for this, but grateful for a further response.

I thought it would be helpful if I provided the YouTube link to Professor Brian Greene's talk about the nature of space, so as to enable responders the opportunity to view it if they wish.  My comments and observations follow.

The link to Prof Greene's 'space', discussion is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJ60Q6-Zx-g&t=152s.  During the explanation, Greene posed the question: 'What is space?' to which responses were provided by astrophysicist prof Alex Filippenko: '... we still don't really know what space is'.  Similarly, theoretic physicist, Prof James Gates says: 'it is one of the deepest mysteries in physics.'  So, I still have a comprehension deficit: what is space?  I have great difficulty in rationalising what is it the is being twisted, curved and rippled. These adjectives are used to describe the properties of space, but little attempt is made to describe the nature of what  is undergoing these transformations, i.e. what is space ‘made’ of.  Now, it appears to me that if one valiantly attempts to convey to the layman the properties of something, then it would help to describe what that thing it is ‘made’ of.  The problems in doing so have been acknowledged by august contributors to Prof Greene's programme.  Nevertheless, and despite sometimes, discussing ‘space’ without mentioning the inextricably linked component of time, Prof Greene attempts to explain the nature of 'space'.  I would be grateful for a further response to elucidate the problem I still have regarding what 'space' is comprised of.

Comment: I respond "Space is made of X!" but then you ask "but what is X made of?" and I reply "X is made of Y!" but then you ask...

Answer (score -1):

I am not a physicist and it was also to me years of investigation to understand. Oversimplifying my (already very oversimplified) knowledge:

On the current best knowledge, it is made of quantum fields. The next question, what is a quantum field. On my current best knowledge ;-), it is a Fock-operator density function.

---

An operator describes the distribution (more exactly, the possible distributions) of something. For example, in the [Schroedinger cat (google!) thought experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat), an operator can describe the state of the cat. It is a very simple operator, because the cat is living with 50% probability and it is dead with 50% probability.

A more complex operator, for example, which describes the electron cloud around an atom. This shows, where can you find the electron with which probability.

The Fock-operator is another step. It describes such a system, where we don't know, how many particles are there. For example, if you compress an electron into an enough small space, its energy will grow (another long story). If you compress it enough, then it won't be sure any more, that only 1 electron will be there. It will be also a possibility, that there will be 2 electrons and 1 antielectron. These things are described by the Fock-operators.

The quantum field relates so to the Fock-operator, as the density relates to the mass: if you integrate it on a volume, you will get the Fock-operator of this volume.

The important part of these quantum fields, that these are interacting. By default, their value is everywhere 0. The particles are the excited states of these fields. Like the waves on the water are the excited states of the by default flat water surface.

Thus, there are no photons, electrons and so on. There is a *single* "photon field", "electron field", "Higgs field" and so on, and the photons, electrons relates to them so, as the individual waves to the sea.

The wonderful cryptic equations what we can find everywhere on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism#Abelian_Higgs_mechanism), describe how are these fields interacting. If you know the operator, in theory you know, what particle can you find, where, with which probability. But, in practice, it doesn't work, because  no one can analitically solve the simplest QFT equation. But there are a lot of other methods (mainly with large computers).

---

The current best knowledge is, that the "space" is made of these, not very much (roughly 20) fields. All the elemental particles are the excitations, the "waves" of these fields.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is grounded in actual physics. A "Fock-operator density function" does not actually mean anything, and you don't get a "Fock operator of a volume" from integrating a quantum field. The only place I know where "Fock operator" actually means anything is in the Hartree-Fock method, not QFT. In QFT, you have Fock spaces and creation/annihilation operators, not Fock operators. Also, it is unclear what it is even supposed to mean that "space is made of quantum fields".